# Seemingly redundant ternary operators in javascript

Tags: javascript, ternary

The following is common code floating around online that checks if cookies are enabled in a particular browser:

```
var cookieEnabled = (window.navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled) {
    document.cookie = "testcookie"
    cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false
}

if (!cookieEnabled) {
    // do some work
}
```

Why are the first and fifth lines ternary statements?  Does

```
var cookieEnabled = (window.navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;
```

catch some case that the following wouldn't?

```
var cookieEnabled = (window.navigator.cookieEnabled);
```

The same goes for the fifth line.

Comment: Funky `cookieEnabled == false` instead of `!cookieEnabled`

Comment: @MikeSav  Thanks for pointing that out.  I often forget about my old posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary statement at the first line is useful in that it coverts a possible non-boolean value into a boolean one.  Consider the following code

```
window.navigator.cookieEnabled = "evil people do this";
```

The above is legal and as the value says evil people do do this.  Without the ternary statement the following code wouldn't execute as expected

```
if (cookiesEnabled === false) { 
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @Andre other than being shorter is there an advantage gained by using `!!`?  Genuinely asking.  Curious if it's a style issue or a functional reason I'm missing

Comment: @JaredPar: I see!  And what if I were to use `if (!cookiesEnabled)`?  Would that mean that I could be rid of the ternary statements?

Comment: @JaredPar AFAIK no, there's no other benefit

Comment: Actually, the == operator compares the implicit boolean values, which ternary statement does not change. The only case where explicitly converting to boolean is really necessary is if you use the === operator (or do other type checks).

Comment: @oxc oops I missed that they used a `==` vs. a `===`. Looks like the current version uses neither ... I'll update my answer to make sense given `===`

Answer (score 2):

To be precise:

```
(window.navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false
```

is equivalent to:

```
!!window.navigator.cookieEnabled
```

However:

```
(document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false
```

can be simply replaced by:

```
document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1
```

Finally:

```
cookieEnabled == false
```

can be changed to:

```
!cookieEnabled
```

So what's the problem with the first case? In JavaScript non-zero numbers, non-empty strings, etc. evaluate to `true`. So `if(window.navigator.cookieEnabled)` passes for `cookieEnabled` being equal to `"foo"` and `42` as well. If you really want to have a variebale of `boolean` type, you must negate it twice.